# class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place

Tags: objective-c++

I have converted my NSString into string, and returning the same but the above error mentioned in the title is printing on console. Please suggest so that i could get away from this issue.

my code is below:

string stringFromNSString(NSString *inNSString)

{

```
return [inNSString UTF8String];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This message is likely to indicate that you're running some function on secondary thread (e.g. using `performSelectorInBackground:`) without creating `NSAutoreleasePool` instance for that thread.

Comment: When i debug it is executing in Thread1 and i am not multi threading any where in my application.